# PyCharm connecting to console is stuck

Tags: python, pycharm, console, environment-variables

I see many have posted the same problem before, but the solutions doesn't help.
I can't run the Console window in PyCharm. I get the error message below shown in the console. And I have set the PATH environment variable using echo %PATH% | clip to copy it. It get stuck at "Connecting to console". What else do I need to do?

```
\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: Settings]